DC motor specs for a 800 gram drone
I new to drone building, and I've been looking for motors for my 800g (liberal estimate) drone. Everything I've found when it comes to brushless motors has been too low on torque to support propellers large enough to generate enough thrust.
Does anyone have suggestions, rules of thumb of calculations to finding propellers and motors to create a desired amount of thrust?
Also, would 7.4 volts be enough or should I look at higher voltages?
Thanks in advance!
